# is it advisable to use dependency injection with Apache Storm?

Tags: performance, dependency-injection, performance-testing, apache-storm

I have written a topology using google guice dependency injection. It runs on cluster but provides poor performance. For testing purpose I've written another topology without any dependency injection, it provides good performance. Does it happening only because I'm using dependency injection. If so, how it is reducing performance?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are using DI. If the injection is happening with each message, is is bound to make things slow. I don't thing that it has nothing to do with storm as such.